# How do I get Post values output to user without Reloading the page?

Tags: html, ajax, jsp

I'm trying to send the user's entered data on JSP page using Ajax. I have sent the variable "vars" on the Jsp page using Ajax.
 Output:
 Registration is Successfull. Welcome null, Your Password is : null, FirstName : null, LastName : null, Email : null, and Date Of Birth is : null,

```
    var output1 = document.getElementById("output1");

    function saveUserInfo() {
        var userName = document.getElementById('username').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        var firstName = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
        var lastName = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var dob = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
        var vars = "username"+userName+"&password"+password+"&firstname"+firstName+"&lastname"+lastName+"&email"+email+"&datepicker"+dob;

        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = 'register.jsp';
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                console.log(hr.responseText);
                output1.innerHTML = (hr.responseText);
            }
        }
        hr.open("POST",url,true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        hr.send(vars);
    }
```

This is my JSP page: I've tried this way but, How can I use the information which I've sent using the variable "vars"?

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import ="javax.sql.*" %>

<%
String user = request.getParameter("username");
session.putValue("username",user);
String pwd = request.getParameter("password");
String fname = request.getParameter("firstname");
String lname = request.getParameter("lastname");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
String dob = request.getParameter("dateofbirth");

 %>

Registration is Successfull. Welcome
<%=user %>,
Your Password is : <%=pwd %>,
FirstName : <%=fname %>,
LastName : <%=lname %>,
Email : <%=email %>,
and Date Of Birth is : <%=dob %>,
```

I'm trying to display the information on the same page without reloading the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in your code is that when you passing variable you are not using "**=**". This operator is used to assign value to some variable . So here in your code

```
var vars = "username"+userName+"&password"+password+"&firstname"+firstName+"&lastname"+lastName+"&email"+email+"&datepicker"+dob;
```

You have forget to give "**=**" while assigning value to variable ,just change it to something like this

```
var vars = "username="+userName+"&password="+password+"&firstname="+firstName+"&lastname="+lastName+"&email="+email+"&datepicker="+dob;
```

For more information refer this-http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost2.shtml